# Proper design pattern for an object with generic parameter of method

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, architecture, refactoring

I have the following problem, I want to be able to authenticate through 3 different sources : firebase, gmail and facebook. Firebase has login/register method, gmail has login method and facebook has login method as well they all take a different parameter like : AccessToken, Intent or LoginData object and return a User object, now I would ike to make a factory that returns ILoginAuthenticator interface or IRegisterAuthenticator

```
interface ILoginAuthenticator<T> {
    suspend fun login(loginCredentials: T): User
}

interface IRegisterAuthenticator<T> {
    suspend fun register(registerCredentials: T): User
}
```

I have no idea how to resolve it by using some design pattern to make it look clean I would like to call a method from for example AuthenticationService which takes a LoginSource and generic data input and than uses the factory, creates object and handles login.

```
sealed class LoginSource {
    object Facebook : LoginSource()
    object Gmail : LoginSource()
}



 //login function takes a generic parameter
    suspend fun <T> login(loginSource: LoginSource, data: T) {
        //factory create an object, by looking at login source
        //handles the login by passing the data
    }



class LoginAuthenticationFactory
@Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth,
    private val firebaseAuthMapper: FireBaseUserMapper
) {
    fun <T> create(loginSource: LoginSource): ILoginAuthenticator<T> {
        when (loginSource) {
            is LoginSource.Facebook -> return FacebookVerificationAuthenticator(
                firebaseAuth,
                firebaseAuthMapper
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is a Repository Pattern. Create a repository that will hide all the implementation logic from Controller. Controller might simply know how to pass UserModel to this Repo and Repo will take care of the rest.

Comment: but by using repository pattern I still will have to create 3 seperate methods for handeling login, gmail login , facebook login and firebase login do I understand you correctly ? Also from my understanding authentication is not a part of repository ? Correct me if I iam wrong and give me more details on your answer, would be awesome. What I want to reach is to be able to use just one method login for all 3 cases because their methods have similar input they take just data required to login and return user.

Comment: Well yes you will need three different methods in your repository, one for each implementation. However, creating a LoginUseCase, that takes a UserModel(username, password), converts it into UserEntity(username, password) and forwarding the same entity to all three methods solves that problem. Taking this entity and doing whatever they want with it is upto 3 different implementation. From your controller perspective, it has done its job of passing data from presentation layer to domain layer.

Comment: I see what you mean however login through facebook requires different parameters you have to call internally some method from facebook sdk which returns AccessToken which you then can use with firebase login method specific for facebook so then I'll have to create 3 methods inside repository interface exposing login details implementation by having a method that takes AccessToken as parameter, maybe there is a better way to do it with repository and I am missing something